# How to set union(or otherelse) type as mandatory key name in interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to union type as enum of keys for some interface for snippeting in vscode.
Assume that some union types,

```
// myunion.d.ts
declare module 'some_module' {
  export type TargetDirectory = 'action'|'nav'|'content'
}
```

And make predefined interface for build preset

```
// preset.d.ts
import 'some_module'
declare module 'some_module' {
export interface BuildPreset {
    ...,
    predefinedTarget: { [ key: TargetDirectory]: string } // Seems not work with this code, No snippet error
  }
}
```

If I declare some variable with `BuildPreset` interface, in `predefinedTarget` field, all values 'action', 'nav', 'content' should exists and no other values should not.
It should be like below,

```
const inter1: BuildPreset = { // This is Okay
  ...,
  predefinedTarget: {
    'action': 'a/b/c/',
    'nav': 'e/f/g',
    'content': 'h/i/j',
  }
}
const inter2: BuildPreset = { // key 'action' is missing -- ERROR
  ...,
  predefinedTarget: {
    'nav': 'A/B/C/',
    'content': 'D/E/F',
  }
}
const inter3: BuildPreset = { // Key 'other' is not possible - ERROR
  ...,
  predefinedTarget: {
    'action': 'a/b/c/',
    'nav': 'e/f/g',
    'content': 'h/i/j',
    'other': 'k/l/m/'
  }
}
```

I have lots of possible values of `TargetDirectory`, so code snippet should check it for preventing mistake. How can I make this possible modifying both `myunion.d.ts` and `preset.d.ts`?
I think I need to totally modify both `d.ts` file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unions, The syntax is `[key in TargetDirectory]`. You are writing it as `[key: TargetDirectory]`, which is incorrect.

The syntax `[key: ...]` is to specify what primitive type the key should be, such as `string`, `number`, or `symbol`.

```
type TargetDirectory = 'action' | 'nav' | 'content';

interface BuildPreset {
  predefinedTarget: {
    [key in TargetDirectory]: string;
  }
}

const inter1: BuildPreset = { // This is Okay
  predefinedTarget: {
    'action': 'a/b/c/',
    'nav': 'e/f/g',
    'content': 'h/i/j',
  }
}
const inter2: BuildPreset = { // key 'action' is missing -- ERROR
  predefinedTarget: {
    'nav': 'A/B/C/',
    'content': 'D/E/F',
  }
}
const inter3: BuildPreset = { // Key 'other' is not possible - ERROR
  predefinedTarget: {
    'action': 'a/b/c/',
    'nav': 'e/f/g',
    'content': 'h/i/j',
    'other': 'k/l/m/'
  }
}
```

[Demo in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgJwOYWAEQJYIgY2AewRCgF4oByOPDfAO3KgB8La4A3B58nO4CW4OQDcAKBEYBEBADMq0AEIBXDABsAJgAVsAZ1RQA3iKjGoYbGojSJENfGSoAXAaMnXAbQDWEYhNiIU6Fi4BEQAuk7awAgSSKKuAL4iiSI8tJFQEnwIAIxOSqqaOnpk+lAA9GWwABYY2hl1APIecCAuZjaW1rb+js6ulNR05E6UZQBGZThl5AA0LsbkrBwjEGXSZUiz8xSpfALDFFVlGGUAVlvGiYmp6ZlSAEx5yupaELrApAbllV7EA8A0ej1KAAW1q2hiUAAtFCoABRABKCIaCLa5k6tBsdgCTkM-SWB3IAEEyvIygBhaZzfq7fiCEZoMpwsoAMQuUCuKTot0kCAAzE8Cq93p9ShUoABpbwUfDAKpSBi1KC0WWmfDaCFjFTQWGI5Go4ztCxWTHdezAXHbf6AwlwcaTKlWgkrNYbdkLWn7EZHE7nakmciy+UIQkeMoqMog6YuK5AA).

You may find more information [here in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

So no, you don't need to completely modify 2 files. Only 1 line in `preset.d.ts` will do.

Comment: Wow why I didnt know this basics? Really appreciate :)